# How to recursively truncate filenames and directory names in powershell?

Tags: windows-7, windows, powershell, windows-server-2008, windows-server-2008-r2

When trying to copy files around a network drive I get the error an error that says the copy operation fails and generates a message that states that the path (file name) is too long. The message also suggests that I shorten the file name and try to copy again.  The problem is I have hundreds of files and folders that have really long names and need a script to cut the lengths of all of these so roughly 100 characters (they do have spaces in the names as well as parenthesis).  I just want to shorten everything that is longer than 100 characters down to 100 characters. I need to make sure the file extensions are not removed or changed either.  I am not very strong with PowerShell so all help is appreciate.

Comment: This could get rather complicated, because if you just truncate the filenames, you could end up with duplicates.  Are the filenames themselves the problem, or is the entire path too long?  If you have long directory names too, why not start there?

Comment: @Charles Burge The file names are unique after the first 15 characters; people at my workplace just enjoy being overly descriptive with their titles so I am trying to find the simplest solution.  I know that a lot of the folders have really long names but so do some of the files so I am trying to be safe with both.  I would be okay if I had a solution that shorterned directory names separately from files names.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet, or do you want us to just write a script for you?

Comment: To be honest I have not tried anything.  I figured it would involve regular expressions and some use of GREP (or the windows equivalent of it) and I am intimidated by those.  So if someone has a solution already or knows of a simple one that would be awesome.  Google did not turn up any good solutions for me but I may not be searching for the right thing.

Comment: Please note that https://superuser.com is not a free script/code writing service. If you tell us what you have tried so far (include the scripts/code you are already using) and where you are stuck then we can try to help with specific problems. You should also read [How do I ask a good question?](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask).